# An efficient way to create a matrix with cython

Tags: python, performance, matrix, linear-algebra, cython

I have a function that calculates a matrix for me but it is really slow. Even in cython it is running slow, so I was wondering if one could do anything to enhance the below code.

EDIT: I've changed or added

`des = np.zeros([n-m+1,m])` to `cdef np.ndarray des = np.zeros([n-m+1,m], dtype=DTYPE)` (This is faster than `np.empty...`
Instead of saying `m/2` I've added a `cdef int m2 = m/2` but that didn't seemed to help anything.

```
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

DTYPE = float
ctypedef np.float_t DTYPE_t

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cpdef map4(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] s, int m): 

  cdef int n = len(s)
  cdef int i
  cdef int j

  des = np.zeros([n-m+1,m])
  for j in xrange(m):
      for i in xrange(m/2,n-m/2-1):
          des[i-m/2,j] = s[i-j+m/2]

  return des, s, m, n
```

Typically `n~10000` and `m=1001`.

Comment: don't forget to check out the output of `cython -a` for details. The generated html file is extremely useful to see the weak points in the code

Comment: Yes, the html file is really helpful, when you wish to see the slow part (or the part that need a lot of conversion), but it is really not very helpful if you have no idea how to go on from there. But I agree with you. I also started with the html file.

Comment: It seems you're just storing simple slices of the array `s`. You could just slice `s` when you need to?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
cdef np.ndarray des = np.zeros([n-m+1,m])
```

You can also make this more specific like you did for the parameter s. You can also turn off bounds checking. Check out the [cython numpy tutorial](http://wiki.cython.org/tutorials/numpy).

You also might want to make a variable:

```
cdef int m_2 = m/2
```

and use that everywhere you have `m/2` because I don't know if Cython will do that optimization for you.

Comment: Instead of tmp var m_2,might be preferable to say `for i in xrange(n-m):` / `des[i,j] = s[i-j+m]` and/or array slice

Comment: I guess I'm a bit late to the party, but you should really add `[DTYPE_t, ndim=2]` to the static type declaration of `des` (~10x speedup). Also interchanging the 2 for-loops helps a little, by aligning array access with the memory layout. This got the run time down to 158 ms on my system from 2.45 seconds for the original code.

Answer (score 2):

It might also help to use `np.empty` instead of `np.zeros`, assuming you'll assign each element:

```
des = np.empty([n-m+1,m])
```

Comment: I found that `np.empty` wasn't the fastest choice.

Comment: I found this to be pretty useful. Reduces the running time from 158 ms to 113 ms!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing m being set anywhere.  At the bottom of your code, you mention that n~10,000, and m=1001.  Does that mean that m is a constant integer of 32 bits?  Not seeing your compilation flags, it's frequently worthwhile to try it with and without `-ffast-math` to see if that makes a difference.  With large arrays and matrices, using a smaller data type usually shows a significant speedup, provided that the smaller data type preserves the range and accuracy that your program needs, though I'm not seeing a large potential benefit on this calculation.

If you could show us the C code that is generated by this, that might help, as well.